# Formatting problem with lyx

Tags: graphics, diagrams, positioning, lyx

I am writing a report in Lyx. I have included many images in the report. And I am having bit of problem with the placement of the image in the final report.

1. I include a image in a section and refer it from the middle of the section. And I would expect the image to be placed in the beginning of the section. Is my understanding correct ?
2. I had inserted image with the understanding of (1). This is how the image looks like in the final report.  The dark stripe you see in the image is the page border. Please let me know where I could be going wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the `lyx` package, but I hope that the following won't be too difficult for you to implement in the lyx medium. I take it that the image you are displaying is contained in some external file (of type jpg? eps? pdf? tiff?). In "ordinary" LaTeX, one would include this object in a `figure` environment -- which can be given a caption and a "label," such that the figure can be cross-referenced elsewhere in the document. The following code fragments may be helfpul for you.

```
\documentclass{article} % or report, book, memoir, etc.
\usepackage{graphicx} % package that provides the command \includegraphics
\usepackage{epstopdf} % load this package if graphics file has .eps format
...
\begin{document}
...
\begin{figure}
\caption{A very complicated looking diagram} \label{fig:diagram}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{name-of-file-that-has-the-diagram}
\end{figure}
...
As Figure~\ref{fig:diagram} makes clear, \ldots
...
\end{document}
```

Happy TeXing!

Comment: Thanks Mico, I think it was because of the image itself, it was not formatted properly. I re-designed the image without any whitespace, and I was able to format it as you suggested in your answer. Thank you so much.